# Kubernetes: Unable to attach or mount volumes - timed out waiting for the condition

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Thanks for reading this, i'm in a real trouble here.

After GKE upgrade of K8 version to 1.21.6, I get this error on some of my pods:

*Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[pentahotspot-fs], unattached volumes=[pentahotspot-fs kube-api-access-222nf]: timed out waiting for the condition*

I'm quite sure that this doesn't have relation with k8 version, I think that something happened with nodes after the upgrade.

In the cluster there is 4 nodes, 2 of them seems to be ok, cause new pods mounts volumes (even the same volume) quick and ok. But, the three ones in image are in the 2 "bad" nodes.

What can i do here?. I really doesn't understand what is happening.

Comment: Can you post the output of `kubectl get pvc,pv -o wide --namespace <of the pods>` to the question.

Comment: Can you post the output of the commands `kubectl describe pv` and `kubectl describe pvc`? Taking out any sensitive information.